# transformations between 1st and 2nd order formalism in pure gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory

I am currently studying about 1st order formalism and I was wandering if the gauge transformation in the vielbein can be mapped to the coordinate transformation of the metric ( pure 2+1 gravity), because I can not work out the details.

Comment: Hi @Ntenia. Welcome to Phys.SE. Consider adding references and links in order to receive useful and focused answers.

Answer (score 2):

if by "gauge transformation in the vielbein" you mean the local lorentz transformation that acts on one of the indices of the vielbein, then the answer is no.

Because this local symmetry is in addition to the general coordinate transformation, and not part of it. In other words all veilbeins that are related by a gauged lorentz transformation correspond to the same metric in a specific coordinate system.